# Как получить результат при поиске в таблице?

Tags: массивы, ios, search, uitableview

У меня есть 2 массива в `TableViewController`. Один с картинками и один с заголовками.

```
_ArrayTitle = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Слон",@"Собака",@"Кошка", nil];
_ArrayImage = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Слон.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Собака.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Кошка.jpg"], nil];
```

И у меня есть `searchdisplayController`.

```
 - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
      NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

      _searchResults = [_ArrayTitle filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}
```

Когда ввожу "1" в строку поиска я хочу получить результат, чтобы заголовок `@"1"` находился с картинкой `@"1.jpg"` в одной ячейке, когда я ищу. Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: а что вы уже пробовали? у вас индекс в массиве цифр совпадает с индексом в массиве картинок, можно когда нашли индекс в одном массиве, взять объект с тем же индексом из второго массива. можно это все дело объединить в массив словарей @{@"index":@"1", @"image":@"1.jpg"}. если в первом массиве только цифры 1...3, то можно его игнорировать вообще, и пользоваться только вторым массивом, и вместо цифр использовать индексы. миллион вариантов.

Comment: Исправил вопрос.
Пробовал объединять два массива в один - ничего не вышло. Со словарем тоже пробовал - ничего... Не могли бы Вы привести пример, который действительно работает?(objective c)  Уже несколько дней не могу решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы связать информацию из разных массивов, необходимо её сгруппировать в один:

```
// Создаём Struct, в котором указываем необходимые значения
struct MyData {
  var title: String
  var image: UIImage
}

// Создаём массив, содержащий элементы MyData
var myData = [MyData]()

// Заполняем массив myData
myData = [MyData.init(title: "title1", image: UIImage(named: "image1.jpg")!), MyData.init(title: "title2", image: UIImage(named: "image2.jpg")!)]

// Затем фильтруем массив myData при поиске
myData = myData.filter { (object: MyData) -> Bool in
let titleMatch = quote.quoteTitle.uppercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText)     
return titleMatch
}
```

Comment: objective-c....